# Change color of a background image (png)

Tags: html, css, png

I have the following CSS selector on my website to add an icon for external links to every href that is not pointing to my own domain (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55891382/257617):

```
a[class=" external-link"]::after {
    content: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAQElEQVR42qXKwQkAIAxDUUdxtO6/RBQkQZvSi8I/pL4BoGw/XPkh4XigPmsUgh0626AjRsgxHTkUThsG2T/sIlzdTsp52kSS1wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    margin: 0 3px 0 5px;
}
```

This is a grey image but the rest of the link has #0273d4 as a color. Is it possible to color that image as well (but not the whole a href background text)?

Comment: use filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802632/8620333

Comment: I agree with Temani Afif, use the filter property. Start with adding `img{hue-rotate(90deg);}` to your CSS file, and adjust the degree value (0-360) of the color shift to your liking.

Answer (score -1):

You could use something link Font Awesome which will allow you to customise the look of the icon like it was text.

```css
.blue {
  color: #0273d4
}

.red {
  color: red
}

.green {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul>
  <li><a class="blue" href="#">External Link <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a></li>
  <li><a class="red" href="#">External Link <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a></li>
  <li><a class="green" href="#">External Link <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

You can find how to start working with Font Awesome in your project [here](https://fontawesome.com/start).

Otherwise you could use the filter property as Temani Afif mentioned. [His Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800705/how-to-change-svg-color-on-hover-when-it-is-an-encoded-css-background-image/54802632#54802632). [Further Reading](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)